# Finding a path n number directories for a specific directory name with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that can find the following patterns.

> folder/*

> ../folder/*

> ../../../folder/*

I'm trying to find it n number of directories.

I currently have this:

```
^folder/(.*)$
```

Which finds:

> folder/*

Comment: I guess something like `(..\/)*folder\/.*` would do the trick... I haven't tested it though. I'm not sure if you want the final asterisk to be a literal asterisk or a 'anything goes' kinda wildcard asterisk...

Answer (score 1):

This would work: `^(?:..\/)*folder\/.*$` (flavour: Python)

Concern being: if the name 'folder' is found somewhere in the path itself, you'll get an incomplete match (unless the path is always specifically like `../`)